# Change background-position on hover using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have divs on my page as below:

```
<div id="switch">
<div id="b1"></div>
<div id="b2"></div>
<div id="b3"></div>
</div>
```

with styling as:

```
#switch{
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url(test.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#b1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#b2{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
#b3{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

I want to change `background-position` to `background-position: 0px -100px;`, `background-position: 0px -200px;` and `background-position: 0px -300px;` when user hover on `b1`, `b2`, and `b3` respectively.

You can see my [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/MFJDE/).

How can I make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $switch = $('#switch');
$('#b1').hover(function() {
    $switch.css({
        backgroundPosition: '0px -100px'
    })
}, function() {
    $switch.css({
        backgroundPosition: '0 0'
    })
}
)
```

This is done for `#b1`, you can do the same for others.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/MFJDE/3/

Comment: but i want the same for b2 and b3

Comment: yea.. i made it here http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/MFJDE/5/  .. refer and comment if any correction needed..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("#b1").hover(function(){
        $("#switch").css('background-position','0px 10px');
    });
    $("#b2").hover(function(){
        $("#switch").css('background-position','0px 20px');
    });
    $("#b3").hover(function(){
        $("#switch").css('background-position','0px 30px');
    });
});
```